# Подсчет количества поднятий iphone с помощью Core Motion

Tags: ios, swift

Подскажите, как можно подсчитать кол-во поднятий айфона вверх\вниз. Пробовал с помощью userAcceleration по Y, но значения хаотично прыгают при перемещении девайса вверх\вниз, не смог найти прямую зависимость.

Comment: Попробуйте запоминать в переменной текущие координаты и считать перемещение относительно них.

Answer (score 0):

Ускорение "по Y" привязано не к движению самого аппарата, а всего лишь к одной из сторон устройства, поэтому любое отклонение самого устройствав руке от определенного положения будет вносить ошибки. Добавим тремор рук, шум датчика и вот вам хаос в показаниях...

Что делать:

1) Получить полное ускорение - онон как раз ориентировано "к уентру Земли"

A = sqrt (A.x^2 + A.y^2 + A.z^2)

2) поставить простой рекуррентный фильтр для обработки вновь поступающих значений

a = a * (1 - k) + A * k

Здесь

a - рабочее значение ускорения, которое вы используете в дальнейших расчетах
A - текущее расчетное значение (см. выше)
k - от 0 до 1 задает "частоту среза" - попросту говоря, определяет насколько влияют резуие изменения в показаниях датчика

3) Отчетливо понимаем, что акселерометр меряет в неrих "попугаях" а не в g.

Впрочем, поскольку вам для использования iPhone в качестве гантели достаточно фиксировать только знак ускорения, это некритично.